# Help me rescue a closed question because I really want to find an answer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I would like to appeal the closing of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162062/how-to-mock-powershell-v3-attributes-in-v2). Frankly I was surprised that it was closed as off-topic; I have asked and answered many PowerShell questions in a similar vein.

As I really want to find an answer and am not sure where to look in the docs, my first step was to add a comment directly to the question to solicit input on why it was off-topic but, alas, no takers there. So *you*, good people of Meta, are my last, best hope. How have I transgressed with my question? How can I change the character of it to make it acceptable? (Or, if you just happen to know the answer to my question, that's fine, too!)

Comment: Looks like you may want to bounty that one.

Answer (score 17):

> How have I transgressed with my question?

You have not.

> Frankly I was surprised that it was closed as off-topic; I have asked and answered many PowerShell questions in a similar vein.

I'm surprised, too. This looks sufficiently related to a programming/scripting context that it would fit on our site (whereas PowerShell questions mainly about end-user usage would probably be a better fit [elsewhere](http://superuser.com)). I've reopened it as it is.

Comment: Much obliged for your assist!